# Run script onclick

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make a DPI calculator for my site and I can't seem to get my head around what I'm doing wrong.

The issue is that I want to run the script onclick so when the user clicks on the button saying Udregn, it'll do the calculation.

Here's my HTML

```
<label>Højde</label>
<input name="height" id="height" type="number" />
<label>Brede</label>
<input name="width" id="width" type="number" />
<label>DPI</label>
<input name="dpi" id="dpi" type="number" value="300"/>
<input name="cm2inch" id="cm2inch" type="hidden" value="0.393700787" /><br />
<input id="udregn" type="button" value="Udregn" onclick="udregn()" />
<br />
<label>Højde i pixels</label>
<input name="heightpx" id="heightpx" type="number" />
<label>Bredde i pixels</label>
<input name="widthpx" id="widthpx" type="number" />
```

And here's the Javascript

```
function udregn(){
    var height=$("#height");
    var width=$("#width")
    var dpi=$("#dpi");
    height.keyup(function(){
        var heightpx=isNaN(parseInt(height.val()* $("#cm2inch").val()* dpi.val())) ? 0 :(height.val()* $("#cm2inch").val()* dpi.val())
        $("#heightpx").val(heightpx);
    });
    width.keyup(function(){
        var widthpx=isNaN(parseInt(width.val()* $("#cm2inch").val()* dpi.val())) ? 0 :(width.val()* $("#cm2inch").val()* dpi.val())
        $("#widthpx").val(widthpx);
    });
}
```

Comment: you do not need `keyup` at all here. if you are using an `onclick` function - just remove all `keyup` as not needed or remove `onclick` - its one or the other.  here is a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/omeysutq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `udregn()` function, you are erroneously setting 2 keyup listeners when I believe you just want to set input values. Remove the event listeners...

```js
function udregn() {
  let height = $("#height");
  let width = $("#width")
  let dpi = $("#dpi");
  let heightpx = isNaN(parseInt(height.val() * $("#cm2inch").val() * dpi.val())) ? 0 : (height.val() * $("#cm2inch").val() * dpi.val())
  $("#heightpx").val(heightpx);
  let widthpx = isNaN(parseInt(width.val() * $("#cm2inch").val() * dpi.val())) ? 0 : (width.val() * $("#cm2inch").val() * dpi.val())
  $("#widthpx").val(widthpx);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Højde</label>
<input name="height" id="height" type="number" />
<label>Brede</label>
<input name="width" id="width" type="number" />
<label>DPI</label>
<input name="dpi" id="dpi" type="number" value="300" />
<input name="cm2inch" id="cm2inch" type="hidden" value="0.393700787" /><br />
<input id="udregn" type="button" value="Udregn" onclick="udregn()" />
<br />
<label>Højde i pixels</label>
<input name="heightpx" id="heightpx" type="number" />
<label>Bredde i pixels</label>
<input name="widthpx" id="widthpx" type="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height.keyup` and `width.keyup` and just execute what's in the functions. You don't need a keyup listeners here.